# Dynamically repaint Panel

Tags: java, swing, paint, graphics2d

I'm trying to do a program that shows an animation of how a cistern fills with time. The problema is that I can't get it to refresh everytime... Here's the code: It Works but it doesn't refresh in the loop, but if I manually resize the window I can see it's new paint in the Panel:

```
static class _cistern extends JPanel{

    private volatile double _maxCapacity;
    private double _flux;
    private volatile double currentStorage = 0.0;
    private boolean IsStarted = false;
    private volatile int Up = 1;

    private Thread Fill = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         @Override
        public void run(){
            while(currentStorage < _maxCapacity){
                currentStorage += _flux;
                try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });

    public _cistern(double MaximunCapacity, double Flux, double CurrentStorage){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        IsStarted = true;
        Fill.start();
    }

     @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.drawOval(getWidth()/20, getHeight()/15, getWidth() - getWidth()/10, getHeight() - getHeight()+20);
        g2.drawLine(getWidth()/20, getHeight()/15+10, getWidth()/20, (getHeight() - getHeight()/15)-10);
        g2.drawOval(getWidth()/20, (getHeight() - getHeight()/15 - 20), getWidth() - getWidth()/10, getHeight() - getHeight()+20);
        g2.drawLine(getWidth() - getWidth()/20, getHeight()/15 +10, getWidth() - getWidth()/20, (getHeight() - getHeight()/15)-10);

        if(IsStarted){ //I know I have some drawings wrong here
                       //I can fix them but I just want this to refresh dinamically. The problema is the REFRESH PAINT.
                       //If you test code and see bad drawing, that's not the problema, I want to see it refreshing :P, that's the question. Don't fix this
            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2.drawOval(getWidth()/20, (getHeight() - getHeight()/15 - 20) - Up++, getWidth() - getWidth()/10, getHeight() - getHeight()+20 - Up++);

            g2.drawLine(getWidth()/20, (getHeight() - getHeight()/15)-10, getWidth()/20, (getHeight() - getHeight()/15)-10);
            g2.drawLine(getWidth() - getWidth()/20, getHeight()/15 +10, getWidth() - getWidth()/20, (getHeight() - getHeight()/15)-10);

            g2.drawOval(getWidth()/20, (getHeight() - getHeight()/15 - 20), getWidth() - getWidth()/10, getHeight() - getHeight()+20);
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks :P

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` instead of a `Thread`, it's safer...

Comment: You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Don't modify the state of your component from within the `paintComponent` method, painting is for painting.  `paintComponent` may be called for any number of reasons, causing unpredictable results

Comment: While I've been screwing around with your code, you should know that Java graphics doesn't respond well to negative values...

Comment: call updateUI and see if that makes any difference

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh hell yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of looking at my code I remembered I was using a Thread to call and EDT... So I just had to add this:

```
private Thread Fill = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         @Override
        public void run(){
            while(currentStorage < _maxCapacity){
                currentStorage += _flux;
                try{Thread.sleep(500);}catch(Exception ex){}
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                revalidate();
                repaint();
                }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `repaint` is, one of the few, thread safe methods in Swing.  `revalidate` is irrelevant in your case, it you're your not trying to update the layout of the container hierarchy

Comment: @MadProgrammer Maybe. I needed to use a Thread, not a timer because it was a simple homework. I don't really like java, but I have to learn it anyways, useful to learn a bit of everything you can. 
I know it's "bad" to use repaint, but as it is said, repaint is better in constant and quick updates (My ORIGINAL loop makes 10 updates by second, not the 500 ms in this example), I should use it instead of update(). Thanks anyways ^_^!!